# Magento 2 in frontend can not able to get the customer custom attribute value

Tags: magento2, custom, customer-attribute

I have created a custom customer attribute, and while create and update customer from backend the value will be saved in Database.

But while do the same thing from front-end the value is not able to save in Database. Moreover, the backend saved value can not able to get using the customer load query.

In `customer_form_attribute` for that particular attribute have the following code
`adminhtml_customer`,`customer_account_edit`,`customer_account_create`

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
         if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.4', '<')) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                'order_limit',
                [
                    'visible' => true
                ]
            );
            //$forms = ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'];
            $forms = ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_checkout','checkout_register'];

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'order_limit');
            $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);

            $attribute->save();
            $setup->endSetup();
        }    
    }
```

Kindly share your thoughts and idea.

Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: Can you paste the InstallData.php / UpdateData.php that contains the creation of these custom customer attribtues

Answer (score 1):

**------- CREATE CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE --------**

**Step 1** : create app/code/Dckap/CustomAttributes

**Step 2** : Create app/code/Dckap/CustomAttributes/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dckap_CustomAttributes" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3** : Create app/code/Dckap/CustomAttributes/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Dckap_CustomAttributes',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 4** : Create app/code/Dckap/CustomAttributes/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Dckap\CustomAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Dckap\CustomAttributes\Setup\CustomerSetup');
                $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



        }

    }
}
```

**Step 5** : Create app/code/Dckap/CustomAttributes/Setup/CustomerSetup.php

```
<?php

namespace Dckap\CustomAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'custom_attribute_value',
            [
            'label' => 'Custom Attributes',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'custom_attribute_value')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']) -> save();               
    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {          
    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

**Finaly run command**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[image]

**----- SHOW CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE IN REGISTRATION FORM ------**

Navigate to **app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Customer/templates/register.phtml**

```
<div class="field required">
     <label for="custom_attribute_value" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Custom Attribute')) ?></span></label>
      <div class="control">
          <input type="text" name="custom_attribute_value" class="custom_attribute_value" id="custom_attribute_value">
      </div>
 </div>
```

**Finaly run command**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your install data script successfully installed your custom attribute(`order_limit`), now you just need to override addition information `phtml` file and set your custom attribute in that.

Create `Stackexchange/CustomAttribute/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_account_edit_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Edit Account Information</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" name="customer_edit" template="Stackexchange_CustomAttribute::form/edit.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create `Stackexchange/CustomAttribute/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml`

```
<div class="field orderlimit">
    <label class="label" for="order_limit"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Limit') ?></span></label>

    <input type="text" id="order_limit" name="order_limit" value="<?= $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute("order_limit")->getValue() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Limit') ?>" class="input-text" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

> Clear cache and review frontend customer account registration page.

**[Source Code](https://github.com/supravatm/magento2-sample-modules/tree/master/custom_customer_attribute/Stackexchange/CustomAttribute)**